# I need help making a buy function for a mock stock buying program

Tags: c++

For a project I'm doing, I need to write c++ code for a buy, sell, and search function. I am very new to c++ so I was basically thrown into the deep end and told to look up other code for help as long as I give credit to where I got it from. A classmate has built the GUI while the other is working on a local database to use. I've written some code so far but i can already tell it is not up to what we need, many errors, and I've never written anything like this before. If possible, I would appreciate some help to look in the right direction,
Below is what i've tried so far. I'm trying to write this so that when a button is selected in our GUI, it will determine if the user has enough money to buy the stock, and if it does, add the stock to their owned stocks and subtract credits that are present. If not enough credits then it would not let the button be selectable or output "insufficient funds"

//buy

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int buyStock(double money, int stockAmnt, double stockPrice) {}

int main() {

    int stockAmnt = stocks
        double money = availableFunds
        double stockPrice = price
        if (availableFunds >= price)
        {
            availableFunds = availableFunds - price;
            stocks++;
        else {
            cout << "Insuficent funds" << endl;

        }
    return money, stockAmnt, stockPrice

        }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Chibiabel, welcome to StackOverflow! It appears some of your code is missing: what data are you searching for? An array? A database?

Comment: Also, I recommend only asking one specific question per question, otherwise you risk getting your question closed for lack of focus.

Comment: Ok I have edited to focus more on just the buy function

Comment: Great @Chibiabel! Now, what is the value of `stocks` and where is it coming from?

Comment: I think I was trying to write it so that stocks could be the amount of stocks the user has when using the program. I'm sorry as this is very rough. I've never written something like this before

Comment: @ChrisHappy I am sorry that my explanation is kinda bare. I'm still new to c++

Comment: What you are trying to do is quite a broad program. My suggestion is that you use a class for buyer and structure for stocks. Look up these two `class` and `struct`.